# Navigate through result pages using ruby mechanize (links have "onclick=" defined)

Tags: ruby, pagination, mechanize, watir

Need help with navigating through result pages using ruby mechanize. I am able to subit form values and download results of first page. Link to next page is

```
 <a href=# onclick="setnext();">Next</a>
```

How to click next and navigate to the subsequent result pages. I have tried

```
 page = r_page.link_with(:text => 'Next').click
```

and also using watir

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new
@login_page = result_page
@l_page = @login_page.link(:text => "Next").fire_event('onclick') 
@browser.goto @l_page
```

I get error message that URL

```
<a href=# onclick="setnext();">Next</a>
```

is not properly formed. I also tried calling the page with page_no as argument but it loads the form submission page and not the results page. Kindly help. 
thank You.

Comment: `<a href=# onclick="setnext();">Next</a> ` isn't valid html, it needs quotes around `#`

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is href="#"

Comment: can u give me result_page url?

Comment: result_page is the results page obtained by form submission, code is as below - r_page = form.submit form.button_with(:id => 'search_button') 
   result_page = r_page.search('//table[2]/tr[2]//a') which is nothing but the link to "Next" page. Hope this helps. Thank You.

Comment: Your best bet is to call setNext() somehow with watir.

Answer (score 0):

The point is, `mechanize` won't interprete the JavaScript function that should be executed when the button is clicked (`onclick="setnext();"`).

You have at least two options:

1. Read and understand the JavaScript code (or debug through it).
2. Use the tools your browser ships with (e.g. `Developer` in Mozilla Firefox, usually accessible by pressing `F12`, Chromium ships with a very similar thing), head over to the network tab and inspect the traffic that actually happens. You will see a `GET`/`POST` request to a specific URL (with some interesting parameters?) when you click the button/link and probably are able to figure out how the URL and the parameters are constructed.

As I am lazy, understand enough HTTP and do not yet enjoy reading JS code enough, I usually use the second approach.

Because `mechanize` will not interprete the JavaScript out of the box, I switch off JavaScript in browser first and see if the page works. If it doesnt, I look at the generated requests (with JS switched on again).

Comment: Page behavior changes with javascript turned off. The js code for setnext() has getElementById("Selected_page").value=2. I thought we can call onclick function using watir but that also is not working, is there a different way to fire onclick javascript function using watir. Thank You.